# Foreign Keys causing issues with Many to One relationship in Spring. Null Pointer error

Tags: spring

We have a User Entity and an Activity Entity where we have a Many to one relationship with User and a One to Many relationships with Activity. We keep getting a null pointer error every time we try to post something. Basically, When I try to add a new activity with an associated foreign key int(for the user). It gives me this message. Don't know why it has a null pointer exception [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKRth.png)

This is what my Activity Controller looks like:

```
@RestController
public class Activitiy_Contoller {
    @Autowired
    private User_Service userService;
    private Activity_Service activityService;

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/getactivity")
    public List<Activity_Entity> getAllActivity()
    {
        return Activity_Service.getAllActivity();
    }
    @GetMapping(value="/getactivityfromid/{id}")
    public Activity_Entity getActivity(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        Activity_Entity temp = activityService.getActivity(id);
        return temp;
    }
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/addActivity")
    public void addActivity(@RequestBody Activity_Entity activity)
    {
        activityService.addActivity(activity);
    }
    @DeleteMapping(value="/deleteActivity/{id}")
    public void deleteActivity(@PathVariable int id)
    {
        activityService.deleteActivity(id);
}
    }
```

My Relationship in Activity Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="activity_type")
public class Activity_Entity {

    //-----------Values-------------

    @Id
    @Column(name="Id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int id;

    //can get the activities for one user with
    //this value using the activity_repo

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name ="user_id")
    public  User_Entity user;
```

My Relationship in User Entity looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class User_Entity {

    // ----------------Values------------------

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    public int Userid;

    //Many groups to one user
    //so can get all groups for one user
    //from this value
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    Set<Activity_Entity> Activities;
    private Set<Group_Entity> Groups;
```

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), or at least a bit more that we can go on than this?  Also, please do not post screenshots.  Better to post stack traces and other errors as code or quoted blocks. - In your case, I almost missed that you had posted the error at all. Specifically, I'd like to know what Activity_Controller looks like at and around line 42.

Comment: Uploaded Sir, Thank you

Comment: Got it to work, I had my services set to static and I kept ignoring the warnings